# How to incorporate Deeplearning4j word2vec with Spark to convert words into its vector representation?

Tags: java, apache-spark, nlp, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I want the DeepLearning4j Word2Vec with incorporate with Spark.I have around 80000 words data for which I want to get the vector representation. Later on, I want to find the synonyms using that vector representation. I am struggling where to write the Word2Vec code portion so that it can be provided to all the vCPU's?

Comment: Have a look at the example file on their repo https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-scaleout/spark/dl4j-spark-nlp/src/test/java/org/deeplearning4j/spark/models/embeddings/word2vec/Word2VecTest.java

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go over their support room to ask, they have replied 24/7 and you can get answer very fast

https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j